# Internalization fmt

Tags: spring, internationalization, taglib

I have the page jsp :

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="f" %>
<%@ page session="true"  %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<%@ page session="true"  %>
<%@ page trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true"  %>
<% 
    String locale = "fr_FR"; 
%> 

<fmt:setLocale value="${locale }"/>
<fmt:bundle basename="com.stock.led.i18n.applicationresources"></fmt:bundle>
```

I have two properties files on package "com.stock.led.i18n.applicationresources" applicationresources_en_US and applicationresources_fr_FR. The applicationresources_en_US file is always used and the _fr_FR is set By fmt SetLocale, i dont understand why ??

Answer (score 0):

After Research i found that the responsible is the header HTTP "Accept-Language" By testing 3 Browsers , the browser installed in French works perfect and the others on english Nope.

Why  `<fmt:setLocale value="${locale }"/>` doesn't force the language and ignore the header HTTP "Accept-Language".